# Dask hdfs3 usage on kerberized cluster

Tags: kerberos, dask

Trying to use dask to read a directory of parquet files on a kerberized HDFS cluster, using the following commands:

```
import hdfs3

hdfs = hdfs3.HDFileSystem(<NAMENODE_FQDN>, port=8020)
```

Which returns the error:

```
ConnectionError: Connection Failed: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

At a terminal on the cluster I have used kinit and can successfully execute hadoop fs commands.  The error shown is coming from the connect method with HDFileSystem, which calls libhdfs3, but to me it looks like the call is not trying to use my kerberos credentials.

Is there a configuration step I am doing wrong or parameter should be changed? I have verified that my namenode and port are correct.

Comment: I was able to connect to the kerberized cluster using the following syntax:
Adding the argument `pars={"hadoop.security.authentication": "kerberos"}`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to connect to the kerberized cluster using the following syntax:

```
import hdfs3

conf={"hadoop.security.authentication": "kerberos"}
hdfs = hdfs3.HDFileSystem(<NAMENODE_FQDN>, port=8020, pars=conf)
```

Comment: `ticket_cache=` and `token=` may also be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried those options first unsuccessfully, although I may have needed the above "conf" option in my answer as well.   My answer above assumed that I had already used kinit at the command prompt prior to starting python.